# How do I create Symbols in SymPy based on user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, calculus

I am trying to create a python programme that takes a function from the user (in terms of x) and returns its derivative using SymPy. However, when I enter letters other than x, SymPy throws an error of undefined symbols. I want it to treat letters apart from x as constant.

For example, if a user enters `a*x**2 + bx`, they should get `2*a*x + b`, and if they enter `z*x**2 + px`, they should get `2*z*x + p`. How can I treat letters apart from 'x' as constants without having to hard-code every letter as a symbol?

I hope my question is clear. Feel free to ask for any clarifications if required.

Comment: Can you provide you code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first parse the user input and collect all symbols. To parse string to sympy expression use `sympy.sympify`. I assume you want to get derivative only W.R.T x. The full code will be:

```py
import sympy as sp
expr = sp.sympify(input('enter expression: '))
print('Derivative w.r.t x: ', sp.diff(expr, 'x'))
```